# Why is bloginfo('stylesheet_url') not rendering my style.css?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

According to the WordPress Codex I should be able to get style.css rendered with  and its not working and nothing is rendering in Console.

This is my header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) here  -->

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/touch-icon-iphone.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/touch-icon-ipad.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/splash.320x460.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 200px) and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait)">
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/splash.768x1004.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)">
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/img/splash.1024x748.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)">

        <!-- load Ink's css from the cdn -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/css/ink-flex.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">


        <!-- load Ink's javascript files from the cdn -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/js/holder.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ink.sapo.pt/3.1.10/js/autoload.js"></script>
```

This is part of my index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<form action="" class="ink-form">
    <div class="ink-grid">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="control-group append-button"></div>
            <div class="control all-100">
                <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search news...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="ink-grid vertical-space">


    <div class="panel">
        <h2>Recent News</h2>
        <div id="car1" class="ink-carousel" data-space-after-last-slide="false" data-autoload="false">

            <ul class="stage column-group half-gutters">
             <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li class="slide xlarge-25 large-25 medium-33 small-50 tiny-100">
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('news-thumb', array(

                        'class' => 'half-bottom-space')); ?>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h4 class="no-margin"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <h5 class="slab"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?></h5>
                      <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
             <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <nav id="p1" class="ink-navigation">
            <ul class="pagination black">
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <div class="panel ink-grid">
        <div class="column-group">
            <div class="all-50">
```

This is my single.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<form action="" class="ink-form">
    <div class="ink-grid">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="control-group append-button"></div>
            <div class="control all-100">
                <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search news...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="ink-grid vertical-space">


    <div class="panel">
        <h2>Recent News</h2>
        <div id="car1" class="ink-carousel" data-space-after-last-slide="false" data-autoload="false">

            <ul class="stage column-group half-gutters">
             <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li class="slide xlarge-25 large-25 medium-33 small-50 tiny-100">
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('news-thumb', array(

                        'class' => 'half-bottom-space')); ?>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h4 class="no-margin"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <h5 class="slab"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?></h5>
                      <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
             <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <nav id="p1" class="ink-navigation">
            <ul class="pagination black">
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <div class="panel ink-grid">
        <div class="column-group">
            <div class="all-50">
```

Comment: What does your browser output at `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `bloginfo()`

get_template_directory_uri() will give you current theme url upto style.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

`‘stylesheet_url‘`

Displays the primary CSS (usually style.css) file URL of the active theme. Consider echoing get_stylesheet_uri() instead.

**Fixed Issue code :**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"> // you have to echo for print a path
```

**Recommanded**

**get_stylesheet_uri()**

Retrieves the URI of current theme stylesheet.

Your code will be :

Replace this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css'?>">
```

Comment: sorry I forget to attach remaining url

Comment: Now its fixed. :)

Comment: You need a slash too `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css'; ?>`

Comment: this answer: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'style.css'; ?>"> is what worked. Really strange coding standard on the part of WordPress though. Thank you all.

Comment: you are forget something here

Comment: you are miss that slash before /style.css